# Alternative to using instanceof in this case?

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism, instanceof

so in this given scenario, I'm not entirely sure how I would implement this in a more OOP way.

Given the following context:

- My game has a superclass Entity
- Creatures (moving entities) and StaticEntities (trees/rocks/etc) extend Entity
- I have an EntityManager class.

In my EntityManager, I check if my mouse is hovering over an Entity. If this is the case, I render an overlay that shows a panel with the Entity's name on it.

In addition to the name, I would also like to display something like some basic stats, such as 'health' and maybe 'power/max hit' or something. Static Entities do not have combat attributes. Creatures however do, but since I return an Entity, I check if the Entity is 'instanceof' Creature and if so: Draw the combat stats. Otherwise just draw the Entity's name.

Could there be a better, more OO-way of designing this construct? I have read that instanceof can be avoided by polymorphism/OO design.

Related code snippet:

```
    if(hoveringEntity instanceof Creature) {
        hoveringEntity = (Creature) hoveringEntity;

        // Custom Util class to draw a String
        Text.drawString(g, "Max hit: " + getDamage(hoveringEntity), x, y, true, Color.YELLOW, Assets.font14);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic). There is no way of telling that by seeing only 3 lines of your code. This is a *design* question affecting lots of your classes.

Comment: There should/could be a `getDisplayInfo()` method that returns what should be displayed. Then you can override that to provide as much or as little information as you want. You're writing in an imperative way at the moment, "if x is entity do this, if x is creature do that" whereas it should be more of "let x do what it needs to do".

Answer (score 0):

With a class sytems like this, `EntityManager`, calling the abstract method `getInfo()` ( implemented in the concrete classes `StaticEntity`and `Creature` ), can retrieve the needed infos.
Maybe it is not the best solution, because it introduces a hard coupling beetween  `EntityManager` and  `Entity`, but it does not need the use of `instanceOf`.

[image]